# lag in irregular time series (xts)

Tags: r, xts

I have a following irregular time series (xts) data.

```
v <- c(1:2, 4:7, 9:11)
x <- xts(v, as.Date("2016-07-20") + v)
x
           [,1]
2016-07-21    1
2016-07-22    2
2016-07-24    4
2016-07-25    5
2016-07-26    6
2016-07-27    7
2016-07-29    9
2016-07-30   10
2016-07-31   11
```

Suppose on "2016-07-30" and "2016-07-31", I want values of a week ago (i.e. "2016-07-23" and "2016-07-24"). So, when I do `lag(x,7)`, it gives data of "2016-07-21" and "2016-07-22".

```
lag(x,7)
           [,1]
2016-07-21   NA
2016-07-22   NA
2016-07-24   NA
2016-07-25   NA
2016-07-26   NA
2016-07-27   NA
2016-07-29   NA
2016-07-30    1
2016-07-31    2
```

I want to know whether there is a function in `xts` that gives me a value of "2016-07-23" on "2016-07-30" and a value of "2016-07-24" on "2016-07-31" if available and return NA if not available.

Expected output:

```
2016-07-30   NA
2016-07-31   4
```

P.S. I do know how to use indirect approach.

Comment: There is no function to do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaUlrich for the confirmation. I have to resort to the indirect approach.